# Show curent user's members based on user_id (Index View)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have a user_id column. Instead of calling for all members how can I call up members based on current user's and user_id?

This is my controller, I tried changing .all to user_id or current_user.id plus many variations based on examples. Still can't get it. I also have no models (using authrocket). The create action also works and inserts the user_id, I have a def current_user at the bottom.

```
class Members::MainsController < ApplicationController

    # Member Profile List
    def index
        @members_mains.user_id = current_user.id
        @members_mains = Members::Main.all
    end

    private

    # Common Callbacks
    def set_members_main
        @members_main = Members::Main.find(params[:id])
    end

    # White List
    def members_main_params
        params.require(:members_main).permit(:mfirstname, :mlastname, :mtitle, :memail, :mphone, :mnotes, :smfacebook, :smtwitter, :smlinkedin, :user_id)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, your index action should be something like this:

```
# Member Profile List
def index
  @current_member = Members::Main.find(current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend to show a list of profiles for all members?

If not, your `index` action can simply be removed. If so, you wouldn't normally filter on a user_id at all for that action and you can remove that line.

To load a member profile for a specific `user_id`, try a `show` action something like this:

`def show
  @members_main = Members::Main.find_by(user_id: params[:id])
end`

That will load a member profile based on the :id from the URL.

If you want to just show the current user's own profile instead, use `current_user.id` which will give you the AuthRocket user's ID.

`def show
  @members_main = Members::Main.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
end`

In either case, you may need to remove `:show` from the `set_members_main` callback.

Lastly, you probably want to remove `:user_id` from `members_main_params` so that users can't modify the AuthRocket user_id. You only want to control that directly (as you already are in the `create` action).

Hopefully that's clear enough to get you on your way, but I could be off a bit based on what functionality you actually intend for `index` and `show`.